# dBase IV Database not indexed

Tags: dbase

I'm working with dBase IV, I can't figure why the error `Database not indexed` occurs after closing the new database created.

reproducing the behavior:

```
create database
add two fields
close all

use database
seek 1
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot tries accidentally found the answer, when I open the database I need to set the **order** with the index

```
USE FOO
DISPLAY STRUCTURE
Field   Field Name   Type      Width  Dec  Index
1       ID           Numeric   6           Y
2       TEXT         Character 60          N
CLOSE ALL
```

Open setting the **order**

```
USE FOO ORDER ID
SEEK <ID_NUMBER>
```